# A couple of object oriented confusion in creating the object

Tags: c#

I have a  couple of object oriented confusion that i am unable to rid of.

```
/// program 1
    class Epos
    {

    }
    class Epos2 : Epos
    {
        Epos obj = new Epos2();
        Epos2 obj1 = new Epos();// Why it fails at compile time
    }
   /// program 2

    class baseclass
    {
        protected baseclass() { }
    }
    class Epos : baseclass
    {
        Epos e = new Epos();
        baseclass b = new baseclass();// Why it fails as per the protected definition  it should be accessible in derive class.
    }
```

Comment: An `Epos` is not an `Epos2`.

Comment: Every dog is an animal `Animal a = new Dog();` but not every animal is dog `Dog d = new Animal()`

Comment: protected constructor means you can only make a sub class of baseclass

Comment: Do you know about the `base` keyword and how to initialize a base class when a constructor is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Ancestor/Descendant relationship.

```
class Dog : Anima{}
class Cat : Animal{}

Animal dog = new Dog(); //Correct
Animal cat=new Cat(); //Correct
Dog d=cat; //Incorrect
```

Every dog is an animal, every cat is an animal, but not every animal can be a dog or a cat.

But you can cast your base object reference to child type if it is the same type:

```
Dog d=(Dog)dog;
```

Also, inheritance is 'is-a' kind of relationship also called Generalization. That means, the inheriting class 'is-a' ancestor class but not necessarily vice-versa i.e. Dog 'is-a' animal but not necessarily vice-versa.

You can also see the following example:

```
class Animal{}
class Dog : Animal {}
class Labrador : Dog{}
class Husky : Dog{}
```

Now, if I say, I have a dog and I will refer to him as an animal, which will always be correct. IN fact, I have a Husky, which I can refer to as a dog or animal which will always be correct.
But if I say, I have a dog, and I will refer to him as Labrador, may not be correct. What if I have a Husky?

EDIT: Just to give you a real world example.

```
class Person
{
    string Name{ get; set; }
}

class Employee : Person
{
    string Id{ get; set; }
}
```

Now, I can do:

```
Person p = new Employee();
Console.WriteLine("Name is: {0}", p.Name);
```

But can I do:

```
Employee e = new Person();
Console.WriteLine("Employee Id is: {0}", e.Id);
```

The above statement would be flawed cos the object is of type person and it does not have property Id, though the reference is of type Employee.

But I can still do:

```
Person p = new Employee();
Console.WriteLine("Name is: {0}", p.Name);
Console.WriteLine("Id is: {0}", ((Employee)p).Id);
```

The above typecast is possible because the refernce i.e. p is of type Person, but the actual inherent object is of type Employee.

Please be mindful that during typecast, compiler only checks the inheritance relationship during compile and not the actual types. The actual types are checked at runtime. Eg.

```
class Teacher:Person
{}
```

Now if you do the following:

```
Person p = new Teacher();
Employee e = (Employee)p;
```

The above code will not generate compiler warning but will fail at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

This is a better example to demonstrate instantiation of extended classes

```
class Animal
{

}
class Dog : Animal
{
    Animal obj = new Dog();  // Allowed
    Dog obj1 = new Animal(); // Not allowed
}
```

Comment: But why i am not getting in terms of memory allotment..in words that is true.

Comment: Your question does not make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

`Epos2` is `inherited` from `Epos`, so the line of

```
Epos obj = new Epos2();
```

will create a new `Epos2` object and `convert` it into an `Epos` implicitly.

`Epos` is not `Epos2`, nor inherited from it, therefore the line of

```
Epos2 obj1 = new Epos();
```

fails and it should fail, read more about object-oriented programming to understand it.

The line of

```
baseclass b = new baseclass();
```

fails, because in `Epos` we are no longer talking about the `class` named `baseclass`, we are talking about `Epos`. Also, may I suggest that you do youe initialization in a `constructor` or a method called in the constructor? This code is sooo ugly.

Comment: What do mean by you do you initialization in a constructor or a method called in the constructor?

Comment: By doing your initialization or a method called in the constructor I mean you write your initialization code inside the block of your constructor or inside the block of a method called directly or transitively inside the block of your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
public class Epos
{
    protected Epos(int x) { this.X=x; }
    public Epos(Epos other) { this.X=other.X; }
    public int X { get; protected set; }
}

public class Epos2 : Epos
{
    public Epos2(int x, string s) : base(x) { this.S=s; }
    public Epos2(Epos other, string s) : base(other) { this.S=s; }
    public Epos2(Epos2 other) : base(other) { this.S=other.S; }
    public string S { get; protected set; }
}

// call as:
// var A = new Epos2(1,"A");
// var b = new Epos(2);
// var B = new Epos2(b, "B");
```